# Getting org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException:

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

```
  //Test code

 class Topic_Service_test
 {
  @Mock
  private Topic_Repository topic_repository;

  @InjectMocks
  private Topic_Service topic_service =  Mockito.spy(new Topic_Service());

  @Test
  void get_topic_test()
  {
    Topic_Table topic = new Topic_Table(2,"java");


    Mockito.when(topic_repository.findById(Mockito.anyInt()))
                                             .thenReturn(Optional.of(topic));
    Mockito.doReturn(topic).when(topic_service.get_topic(2));//.thenReturn(topic);

    Assertions.assertEquals(topic,topic_service.get_topic(2));
  }
 }

 class Topic_Service
 {

   @Autowired
   private Topic_Repository topic_repository;

   public Topic_Table get_topic(int id)
   {
     System.out.println("get topic exec");
     return topic_repository.findById(id).orElse(new Topic_Table());
   }
 }
```

According to me, topic_service.get_topic(2); in Topic_Service_test class should return the object according to Mockito.doReturn(topic).when(topic_service.get_topic(2)); but actually 
it is showing some error, which I am not getting it.

ERROR SHOWING:-
      org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
      Unfinished stubbing detected here:
      -> at 
      io.practice.practice_course_api.
                             Topic_Service_test.get_topic_test(Topic_Service_test.java:53)

```
  E.g. thenReturn() may be missing. 
  Examples of correct stubbing:
 when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
 when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
 doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
 Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if   
 completed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax. It should be:

```
Mockito.doReturn(topic).when(topic_service).get_topic(2);
```

That is the syntax you want to use on spies to avoid side-effects (for example: if the method invocation would throw an exception).

---

```
@Mock
private Topic_Repository topic_repository;

@InjectMocks
private Topic_Service topic_service = Mockito.spy(new Topic_Service());
```

Also instead of using it like this, the cleaner way would be to use constructor injection. Consider adding a constructor that has a parameter `Topic_Repository` and then manually create the `spy` in your test.

Comment: why Mockito.when(topic_service.get_topic(2)).thenReturn(topic); not working?

Comment: If you use that syntax on a spy the real method might be invoked. You did not mention what kind of exception you receive when you write it like that, so I can only assume that its related to the invocation. If you require more information consider adding the stacktrace for this case to the question.